# Convert List<SomeObject> to List<T>?

Tags: c#, generics, wpfdatagrid

After almost 20 years using Visual FoxPro, I'm suffering with strong type language. :).

I'm trying to create a generic method, using one interface, to set a `DataGrid.ItemsSource` property.

Here we go...

First, I have a class (POCO):

```
public class PersonVO
{
    public int PersonID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then I created an interface:

```
public interface IBussiness
{
    List<T> GetAll<T>();
}
```

And then, other class that implements this interface...

```
public class PersonBLL : IBussiness
{
    public List<PersonVO> CreateNewList()
    {
        List<PersonVO> list = new List<PersonVO>();
        list.Add(new PersonVO() { PersonID = 1, Name = "Robert" });
        list.Add(new PersonVO() { PersonID = 2, Name = "Julie" });
        list.Add(new PersonVO() { PersonID = 3, Name = "Bernard" });
        return list;
    }

    public List<T> GetAll<T>()
    {
        return CreateNewList();
    }
}
```

The statement `return CreateNewList()` shows an error:

> C#: An instance of type
>   'System.Collections.Generic.List' can
>   not be returned by a method of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

So I changed this method to:

```
public List<T> GetAll<T>()
{
    return CreateNewList() as List<T>;
}
```

It compiles!

Now, my problem starts... I have a WPF usercontrol `MyTabItemList`.

My point is, I create a new WPF TabItem at runtime, and inject my BLL class (in this example `PersonBLL`, but in real world I have a lot of them...).

```
MyTabItemList myTabItem = new MyTabItemList(new PersonBLL());
```

MyTabItemList is something like this:

```
public partial class MyTabItemList : TabItem
{
    IBussiness oBLL;
    public MyTabItemList(IBussiness oBLL)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.oBLL = oBLL;
        MyGrid.ItemsSource = oBLL.GetAll<object>();
    }
}
```

It runs ok, but doesn't work like I would like it to.

`oBLL.GetAll<object>()` always returns `null`.

If I change `<object>` to `<PersonBLL>` (like below), it works, but in this case `MyTabItemList` just works with `PersonBLL` class:

```
MyGrid.ItemsSource = oBLL.GetAll<PersonBLL>();
```

What should I do to make it work?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why do you want to return a generic list from a none generic component like this?

```
public interface IBussiness
{
    List<T> GetAll<T>();
}
```

I think your purpose is:

```
public interface IBussiness<T>
{
    List<T> GetAll();
}
```

and make your `PersonBLL` implement `IBussiness<PersonVO>`:

```
public class PersonBLL : IBussiness<PersonVO>
{
    public List<PersonVO> CreateNewList() { ... }

    public List<PersonVO> GetAll()
    {
        return CreateNewList();
    }
}
```

That's one of the normal patterns.

Comment: GREAT! ..... Just one typo (I think). public List<PersonVO> GetAll() { ... }   /// There is no <PersonVO> between GetAll and (), right??? ... Thank you!

Comment: Comment: In my console test application, it works, but I can't use it in a XAML usercontrol. I'm reading another questions here to try workaround it...

Answer (score 1):

Jeffrey's answer is correct but it sounds like you're actually trying to implement the repository pattern using generics

[Have a look here](http://www.remondo.net/repository-pattern-example-csharp/) for more information - you may be trying to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: Hey... It will really help me! CRUD is exactly my point! Thank you again!

Comment: @RodolfoDuarte Just to be clear - repositories sit on top of the DAL (data access layer/CRUD). If you're new to .Net, I strongly suggest you look into using the Entity Framework ([See Here](http://www.jasondeoliveira.com/2011/07/tutorial-code-first-with-entity.html)). It's powerful, flexible and once you've got your head around it, it's really easy too.

Comment: Yeah! ... I'm studying (and using) EF. I bought three books by Julie Lerman and it is ok for me. Now, I'm trying to test my EF class using WPF as user interface... But I don't want to write one UI for each EF class... I want to write a generic UI (in this case, GridList) that works with any EF class. I think I'm going good. Thank you for your attention!